# In equation of torque and angular momentum what is the position vector exactly

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, vectors, torque

In terms of vectors:
$$
L = r \times p
$$
and torque:
$$
T = r \times F
$$
In both these cases what exactly does the $r$ vector represent? Is it vector from origin of axis or center of mass? How would $r$ look like in an example of a spinning disc? Any other good examples to improve intuition?

Comment: $r$ is position from origin of framework, but sometime it is easier to choose center of mass framework particularly when center of mass is in uniform motion

Comment: Im sorry i am still confused. What is the framework? How do I know where the origin is? Can i get an example with the disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $r$ in the equations for angular momentum or torque for example, is a position vector, however, the specifics of the vector depend on the problem you are working.

For example, if you are wanting to calculate the angular momentum or torque of an object you must choose some reference point to define the $r$, or *moment* in the equations, this can be the origin of your chosen system of coordinates, however, it does not *have* to be. For the case of a spinning disc, one may choose to calculate its angular momentum about any given point in space, e.g. the disk doesn't have to be simply spinning about its central axis; the disc could be spinning all the while orbiting some other point; in such case the disc would have angular momentum about the point it orbits in addition to angular momentum about it's central axis. Thus it is important that one completely specify the degrees of freedom present in one's problem.

Often, however, the angular momentum about the center of rotation is of special importance in problems, for example if you have the problem of a disc of spinning about its center, then one might want to know how much angular momentum it possesses. One can calculate this using the definition of angular momentum as written in your post where the $r_i$ are position vectors of the particles of mass $m_i$ that make up the disc, they point from the center of the disc's rotation to the specific point of mass $m_i$. For an extended rigid body like a disc the formula becomes:
$$L=\int\int\rho(\vec r)\omega r^2\;dA,$$
where the integral is a double integral over the geometry of the disc and $\rho$ is the density. When it is the case that a symmetric object like the disc is of uniform density and the axis of rotation coincides with its axis of geometrical symmetry, or centroid, then the $r$ in the formulas is also the center of mass. In general it is not necessary to worry about calculating these kinds of integrals for many simple objects, e.g. the moment of inertia tensor may already be known are simply looked up and the angular momentum of rigid bodies like the disc and others are given as the simple linear relation:
$$\hat L=\mathbf{I}\hat \omega.$$
Here $\mathbf I$ is the moment of inertia *tensor* and $\hat L$ and $\hat\omega$ are column matrices. In a simple case like the disc rotating only about the one axis, then one may do away with the vectors and tensors and calculate the magnitude of the angular momentum via the simple algebraic relation:
$$L=I\omega.$$ Where $I$ is simply a number depending on the mass and various geometrical quantities, that can frequently be looked up from a table of moment of inertias for various rotating objects, and $\omega$ is the magnitude of the angular velocity.
The meaning of $r$ and the relations for angular momentum are analogous to the case of torque.

Whether or not the $r$ is taken from the origin or from the center of mass, or other point all depends on what quantities you are trying to calculate as the case demands.

Comment: Lets say I have the reference coordinate system as the axis of rotation of the disk. then, how come whey I use $I = \frac{1}{2}Mr^2 $ and $\omega = \frac{v}{r}$ I get $\frac{1}{2}mrv$ but when I take cross product, I get $-rmv\sin(\theta)$. I defined $\vec{r}$ to be $r\cos(\theta)\mathbf{i} + r\sin(\theta)\mathbf{j}+0\mathbf{k}$ and momentum vector to be simply $mv\mathbf{i}$. What would theta represent in this case?

Comment: If you want to find that angular momentum of a disc as specified, you cannot simply take the cross product without also integrating over the entire geometry of the disc. The formula $\vec L=\vec r\times\vec p$ only applies to a single point particle not an extended rigid body. So you must use $L=I\omega$

Comment: ok one last question. slightly off topic but what then is $\theta$?

Comment: @thewhale Well, $\theta$ is the angular displacement of the rotating body or disc. It is often used with the relation: $$s=r\theta.$$

Answer (score 1):

In mechanics, there are three places where this equation shows up, and it has the *same* geometric interpretation each time.

[image: fig1]

**In each case, the $\vec{r}$ is the vector from the origin (or the point of reference/point of summation) to an arbitrary point that lies on a 3D line in space.**

- **Torque** - A force $\vec{F}$ acts along a line in space called **the line of action**. The force vector is free to slide *along* this line without changing the nature of the situation. The force in space causes an equipollent torque about the origin $$\vec{\tau} = \vec{r} \times \vec{F}$$ where $\vec{r}$ is the location of any point along the line of action.

  By definition, if the line passes through the origin, then no torque is generated, and there is twisting about the origin.
- **Angular  Momentum** - Body momentum $\vec{p}$ acts along a line in space called **axis of percussion**. The momentum vector is free to slide *along* this line without changing the nature of the situation. Momentum in space causes an equipollent angular momentum about the origin $$\vec{L} = \vec{r} \times \vec{p}$$ where $\vec{r}$ is the location of any point along the line of action.

  By definition, if the line passes through the origin, then the body has no angular momentum about the origin.
- **Velocity** - A rotation $\vec{\omega}$ acts about a line in space called **axis of rotation**. The rotation vector is free to slide *along* this line without changing the nature of the situation. Rotation in space causes a tangential velocity about the origin $$\vec{v} = \vec{r} \times \vec{\omega}$$ where $\vec{r}$ is the location of any point along the line of action.

  By definition, if the line passes through the origin, then no velocity is generated, and the body is purely rotating about the origin.

The perspective above is the basis of what is called the *screw theory* of rigid body mechanics. It offers a geometric interpretation of the quantities involved, with the connection between lines in space and the above line vectors.